# Пожалуйста ответьте на вопросы Perl программисты!

Tags: perl

Почему говорят, что Perl умер если релиз говорят о его развитии? Где применяется Perl? Что может perl чего не может python? Можно ли на Perl писать крупные порталы, проекты с высокой нагрузкой? Какую версию изучать 5 или 6? ? Какие книги посоветуете, кроме священного писания "Программирования на Perl"? Мне Perl нравится, но стоит ли тратить время на его изучения. Всюду мне говорят изучай python как более современная альтернатива, но python мне не очень нравится, особенно синтаксическая значимость отступов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Почему говорят, что Perl умер если релиз говорят о его развитии?

Он умер для тех, кто его не осилил.

> Где применяется Perl?

на нем разрабатываются большие проекты. Вот к примеру интервью о одном таком [проекте](http://rabota.ua/Info/Employer/post/2013/10/29/interview_with_Alexej_Varianik_Provectus_IT.aspx).

> Какую версию изучать 5 или 6? ?

начните с [этого](http://pragmaticperl.com/issues/07/pragmaticperl-07-%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-yapc-europe-2013-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5.html). Если коротко, то учите 5, он практически везде используется. А на 6 - посматривайте.

> Всюду мне говорят изучай python как более современная альтернатива

а разве они говорят "изучай вместо"?

на почитать:

- [Perl умер. Да здравствует Perl!](http://habrahabr.ru/post/31192/)
- [Почему корпорации ненавидят Perl?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38014/)

Книги на почитать:

- [Perl best practice](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/search?q=Perl%20Best%20Practices)
- [Perl Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003135.do)
- [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/index.html)